# Listening to URL with Android Websocket

Tags: java, android, url, websocket

I made a simple web-chat with SpringBoot, it works fine. Now I'm trying to connect to it with an Android client.

In SpringBoot I handle different URLs. "/message-flow" is for real message transfer, "/echo" is a testing URL returning the same text. Both work properly. Here's my Controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/message-flow")
public void broadcast(@Payload Message message, Principal principal) throws SQLException {
    
    String sender = principal.getName();
    String receiver = message.getReceiver();
    
    // Send message to the receiver
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(receiver, "/queue/reply", message);
    
    // Some extra actions: saving to DB and so on
}


// For android developing
@MessageMapping("/echo")
public void echo(@Payload String message) {
    
    message = "Server returns: " + message;
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue/echo-reply", message);
}
```

From the client-side (browser) I send messages to one URL and listen from an other. For example, I send real message like this: `stompClient.send("/app/message-flow", {}, userJson);` and testing echo message like this: `stompClient.send("/app/echo", {}, "test text");`. And this is how I connect and receive:

```
function connect() {
    
    var socket = new SockJS("/chat-messaging");
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        
        stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", function (data) {
            
            var message = JSON.parse(data.body);
            broadcastMessage(message);
        });
        
        stompClient.subscribe("/queue/echo-reply", function (data) {
            
            console.log("we got some message");
            var message = data.body;
        });
    });
}
```

My app is deployed on [Heroku](https://chat-vu.herokuapp.com/). Now I need to connect to it from Android.

**SO**, the first question is: where are different URLs in Android Websocket? I've read many guides and there is only endpoint URL defined.

The second issue is that my Android app does not connect to my Heroku app. Please take a look on my Android code:

```
class ServerConnection extends AsyncTask {

    private static final String SERVER = "ws://echo.websocket.org"; // it works
    private static final String CHAT_SERVER = "ws://chat-vu.herokuapp.com/chat-messaging"; // it doesn't work
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        WebSocket ws = null;
        try {
            ws = connect();
        } catch (IOException | WebSocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        String text = "hi from app";
        ws.sendText(text);

        // Close the WebSocket.
        //ws.disconnect();

        return null;
    }
    
    private static WebSocket connect() throws IOException, WebSocketException
    {
        return new WebSocketFactory()
                .setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT)
                .createSocket(CHAT_SERVER)
                .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                    // A text message arrived from the server.
                    public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                        Log.d("myLog", "We got some text: " + message);
                    }
                })
                .addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE)
                .connect();
    }
}
```

As I send my test message to "ws://echo.websocket.org", I get it back. As I send it to "ws://chat-vu.herokuapp.com/chat-messaging", I get an error:

```
2020-07-19 10:44:53.399 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.OpeningHandshakeException: The status code of the opening handshake response is not '101 Switching Protocols'. The status line is: HTTP/1.1 200 
2020-07-19 10:44:53.399 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.HandshakeReader.validateStatusLine(HandshakeReader.java:232)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.400 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.HandshakeReader.readHandshake(HandshakeReader.java:54)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.400 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.readHandshake(WebSocket.java:3412)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.400 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.shakeHands(WebSocket.java:3291)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.400 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.connect(WebSocket.java:2326)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.401 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at ru.aconsultant.firstproject.ServerConnection.connect(MainActivity.java:316)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.401 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at ru.aconsultant.firstproject.ServerConnection.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:288)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.401 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.401 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.401 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.401 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.402 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-07-19 10:44:53.402 8881-9254/ru.aconsultant.firstproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

But even if it connects I still need to figure out how to send message to "/echo" or "/message-flow" and also how to listen to different URLs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `From the client-side (browser) I send messages to one URL and listen from an other.` That is pretty strange to begin with. Normally one would send a message to the server and then listen for a reply. And i wonder how you would tell a browser to get the reply from another url.

Comment: `The second issue is that my Android app does not connect to my Heroku app. ` Please tell things right away; `The second issue is that my Android app does connect to a websocket.org url but not to my Heroku url`.

Comment: @blackapps `And i wonder how you would tell a browser to get the reply from another url.` Why do you wonder if there's a code in my question? JS represents this part.

Comment: Why so unfriendly? Does that help to solve your problem? Indicating the code would help. Reacting to all comments would help.

Comment: @blackapps I dont see anything unfriendly, sorry if yoy do. Do you see a JS code in my question? It represents subscribing on 2 URLs.